# OperaDriver is not navigating to desired URL

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have tried to open a URL using the [OperaDriver](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/operadriver/). My issue is that I am getting browser launched but the desired page is not getting loaded. Below is the code.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {


/*  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
      capabilities.setCapability("opera.binary","C:/Program Files(x86)/Opera/opera.exe");
      driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities); 
      */

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      capabilities.setCapability("opera.binary","Opera/opera.exe");
      //capabilities.setCapability("opera.log.level", "CONFIG");
      capabilities.setCapability("opera.port", "-1");
      capabilities.setCapability("opera.profile", "");
       driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);



}

@Test
public void testCreateAccount() throws Exception{

driver.navigate().to("http://google.com/");



}
```

I am using Opera browser version 11.10 and running test as JUnit.

When it fails, the following is returned in the console.

> Exception in thread "stp-thread"
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException at
>   sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys(SelectorImpl.java:75) at
>   com.opera.core.systems.util.SocketMonitor.pollSockets(SocketMonitor.java:132)
>   at
>   com.opera.core.systems.util.SocketMonitor.poll(SocketMonitor.java:108)
>   at com.opera.core.systems.scope.stp.StpThread.run(StpThread.java:60)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you let it fail, what's the error that's returned?

Comment: Lyndon i am getting following error in console, Exception in thread "stp-thread" java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException
 at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys(SelectorImpl.java:75)
 at com.opera.core.systems.util.SocketMonitor.pollSockets(SocketMonitor.java:132)
 at com.opera.core.systems.util.SocketMonitor.poll(SocketMonitor.java:108)
 at com.opera.core.systems.scope.stp.StpThread.run(StpThread.java:60)

Comment: Added your error message to the question.  I'm not certain about this one.

Answer (score 2):

try this method its working fine  for me.....

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();   capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");               capabilities.setCapability("opera.autostart ",true);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
driver.get("http://google.com/");
```